# Killing the mail tag - Is it time?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just beefed up the [email](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) and [mail.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail.app) descriptions as well as edited the few questions that had been tagged with mail.

I've proposed mail be a synonym of email.

If you are curious - only 2 of the mail questions related to iOS - they already had some flavor of iOS and the email tag. About 5 questions tagged only mail were for mail.app, but more than 75% of the mail tags were redundant and already tagged email and the mail.app tag was not needed for those questions.

Comments, suggestions?

Time to vote on https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms if you like or dislike this synonym.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, my initial reaction was to rename email to mail, as the latter seems to be the word Apple prefers to use. However, as "mail" can also be used to mean "Mail.app" or "iOS Mail" I agree that it makes sense to force people to disambiguate, otherwise the tag itself is worthless. Whether that can be accomplished by making the tag wiki clear that "mail" is about "email" or whether we should set up the synonym mail -> email or even if we should just ban "mail" altogether, I don't know.

Comment: I struggle a bit with a tag name for the mobile mail client - iOS-mail is kludgy, mobile-mail is the closest to how the program itself is named. As to mail or email - I don't' care - but feel one should be a synonym of the other. It was 10 to 1 in favor of email when I started editing this evening.

Comment: I lean towards "ios-mail" because [Apple itself has used the term](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22ios+mail%22+site:apple.com+-inurl:discussions+-inurl:itunes).

Comment: Internally, the locations of the binaries are `/Applications/Mail.app`
 and `/Applications/MobileMail.app` and most developers use this to differentiate between the mobile builds of safari and mail. Instead we get to read the tea leaves in public documentation :-) Since there are only 6 hits for iOS Mail - it's clear that apple prefers to call it Mail and hope/expect/demand that context make the iOS / Mac line clear. Unfortunately, this goes against the way tags are thought of here needing to be able to stand alone.

Comment: What about `Mail.ipa` for the iOS mail client ?